# java indexOf find aaa and replace with b

Tags: java, indexof

I am trying to find a pattern of "aaa" and replace it with "b" for example using indexOf but it isn't working correctly:

```
private boolean matchCase;
private boolean wholeWords;

private void containsSearchValue(String currentValue, List<MnvrFindContainer> foundList, String textToFind, int i, int j)
{

    if .....

    else if (matchCase && wholeWords && currentValue.contains(textToFind))
    {

        String s = currentValue;
        String pattern = textToFind;
        int index = 0;
        int lengthOfPattern = 0;
        do
        {
            index = s.indexOf(pattern, index + lengthOfPattern);
            lengthOfPattern = pattern.length();

            MnvrFindContainer fContainer = new MnvrFindContainer();
            fContainer.row = i;
            fContainer.column = j;
            foundList.add(fContainer);

        }
        while (index > -1);

    }          
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `str.replace("aaa", "b");`?

Comment: There could be different patterns like aaa, aaaa, abaaba, and I want to replace all instances of "a" with "b" for example.

Comment: then  str.replace("a", "b")  ??

Comment: @TamaraRobbins In that case `str.replaceAll("a", "b");` will do the magic.

Comment: The code you posted has lines that are not relevant to your question (the i, j, Container, etc.) and is missing an aspect that is relevant to your question (the replacement string). Create a simple class with a simple test method that attempts to solve the problem you are facing. You will probably find the solution. otherwise, post that essentialized code here.

Comment: Do you want each `a` to be replaced by a `b` or a sequence of them with a single `b`? Or each `aaa` with 1 `b`?